# How to find extreme values of $f= \sin x/x$?

Tags: trigonometry

How to find extreme values of $\dfrac{\sin x}{x}$?
Tried let
$$f'=\dfrac{x\cos x-\sin x}{x^2}=0$$
So $$x\cos x-\sin x=0$$
So for $\cos x \neq0$ have $\tan x =x$
Any hint how to go further?

Comment: You want to find the locations (argument values $x$) where $f$ has a local extremum $f(x)$? Or you want to find the extreme values $f/x)$ themselves? If you are only interested in _global_ extremum places, you can leave out most. Is $f$ defined in $x=0$?

Comment: @JeppeStigNielsen Yes, thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's not much else you *can* do. You can say roughly where $\tan x=x$ (calculators can give you as many decimals as you want, though), but it's not really a solvable equation in any satisfactory way.